# assembly program to find the smallest among two numbers

Tags: assembly, 8085

how do i assembly program to find the smallest among two numbers.

assuming that 
first number is located a memory address : 0x2001
second number is located a memory address : 0x2002

store the smaller number in Accumulator

Here is what i attempted :

```
LDA 0x2001
MOV B, A
LDA 0x2002
CMP B
JNC smaller
exit
smaller :
MOV A, B
exit : HLT
```

is my solution correct?

Comment: that is exactly i want to know, if my answer is correct, i don't have any means to test it!

Comment: Can you walk through it while looking at the values in memory?

Comment: So go get an [emulator](http://gnusim8085.org) and try it....

Comment: @CarlNorum - thanks, i will chk that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XRA             ; clear the accumulator
MVI B, 30H      ; load a number to B Register
MVI C, 40H      ; load a number to C Register
MOV A, B        ; Move the content of B to A
CMP C           ; Compare value of C against A
JNC SMALL       ; Jump if smaller
**JMP END**         ; Halt program if not small
SMALL: MOV A, C ; save smaller num in accumulator
**END: HLT**
```